# Define a user-defined class as DataContract or not

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

I want to consume a WCF REST service using an AJAX call.

Suppose I have the following where `Person` is a user-defined class:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPerson
{
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]   
    [OperationContract]
    Person GetPerson();
}
```

What are the differences between defining a `Person` as a `DataContract` and if I do not define `Person` as a `DataContract`?

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

On the client side I can always use the following no matter whether `Person` is defined as `DataContract` or not, right?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
        $("#Button1").click(function() {
            $.getJSON("<url of the service>/GetPerson", CallBackMethod);
        });
    });

    function CallBackMethod(result) {
        alert(result.FirstName);
        alert(result.LastName);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data contracts are just one form of serialization that the .NET Framework supports; they are essentially the replacement for pre-WCF XML Serialization. This is all done through the DataContractSerializer, which is responsible for turning your object into serialized XML that matches the data contract. This is the serializer class that is used by WCF and the ASP.NET JSON code, among other pleaces.

In theory, you should tag your contract objects with the DataContract and DataMember attributes to make clear what they are for. In practice, the DataContractSerializer will make a data contract out of any custom type you give it; it will infer the DataContract and DataMember attributes for you if you leave them off. Adding them gives you more control over how the serialization works, in exactly the same way that adding XML serialization attributes did. Lacking the explicit attributes, all public fields in your object become part of the data contract.

So, the real answer to your question is that Person is *always* defined as a DataContract, at least as far as the serializer is concerned; adding the attributes to your class and all of its public members will produce the same effect. IMO, there's no good reason *not* to do so: it costs you a few milliseconds of typing, and if you don't the runtime will just pretend you did anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in some cases, a type may implement more than one programming model. For example, it could be both a DataContract and an IXmlSerializable, or it could be both a CollectionDataContract and an IXmlSerializable. The Data Contract programming model -- which goes beyond just DataContractAttribute -- dictates how such types should be serialized. Please see [the awesome blog post here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/02/22/wcf-serialization-programming-model.aspx) for details on how this works.

To answer your specific question, until .NET 3.5 SP1, you could NOT serialize "POCO" types (plain old C# types) unless they were decorated with DataContractAttribute. Once POCO support was introduced, however, it made no difference. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/08/10/serializing-plain-old-clr-objects-poco-types-with-datacontractserializer.aspx) for details.

Hope this helps!